# Popup windows doesn't move up when Surface keyboard is shown in Windows 8 store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have a windows store application that requires the users to enter data via numerous textboxes.

When a textbox near the bottom of the screen has focus the on screen keyboard appears and moves the content of the page up. This is great and what I want.

My problem occurs when I have a popup window. When my popup window appears it is practically full screen. The popup window's child is a user control which again has lots of textboxes on it. When one of the textboxes near the bottom of the page is selected, the keyboard appears but the screen doesn't move up so the keyboard is appearing over the selected textbox.

This is the code I use to display my popup:

```
if (myPopup == null)
{
    myPopup = new Popup();

    myPopup.Child = new PopupFrom();

    // open the Popup                
    myPopup.IsOpen = true;
}
```

I also manually size the popup when the layout is updated

```
private void popup_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
{
    if (Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.Value == Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.FullScreenLandscape)
    {
        popup.Width = 1280;
        popup.Height = 680;
    }
    else
    {
        popup.Width = 680;
        popup.Height = 1280;
    }
}
```

So my question is how can I move the popup window up when the keyboard is shown and overlapping one of the textboxes near the bottom of the popup?

Thanks in advance.

I'm using C# & XAML to write this windows 8 store app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my app, I listen to the [InputPane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane%28v=win.10%29.aspx) show/ hide events. These events tell you when the keyboard or other input device is shown/ hidden:

```
var pane = InputPane.GetForCurrentView();
pane.Showing += pane_Showing;
pane.Hiding += pane_Hiding;
```

In your event handlers, you can use the [`OccludedRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane.occludedrect%28v=win.10%29.aspx) property to determine how big the input area (e.g. keyboard) is. Then you can shift your popup so that it does not cover this rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen to **gotFocus** event for overlapped textboxes in order to modify popup's child dimensions. Also, I recomend to use a **ScrollViewer** as child for popup, to allow scrolling to above content.
Something like : `emailBox.GotFocus += (s, o) => AdjustPopup();` Good Luck!

Comment: I don't want to modify the dimensions. I could do that within popup_LayoutUpdated if I wanted to do that. I want to move the whole content up like a normal page does when the keyboard is shown

Comment: If you can find another way to achieve this visual behavior, let us know, it will be interesting.